# How to bring Screens inside to MDTabs in KivyMd .whats wrong in the code? do i require latest KivyMD version?

Tags: python, pycharm, tabs, kivy, kivymd

The code initially uses  MDTopAppBar in load2.kv . When loading the app  3 Tabs are visible. but  cannot bring in the screens.  There are no errors. How can this be done?Further how do i naviagate through tabs using the menu.

```
1. main2b.py
```

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define the content for each screen as separate classes
class Screen1Content(MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class Screen2Content(MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class Screen3Content(MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class TabContent(MDFloatLayout, MDTabsBase):
    pass


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.root = Builder.load_file('load2.kv')

    def build(self):
        menu_items = [
            {
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "height": dp(56),
                "on_release": lambda x=f"Item {i}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in range(5)
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=4,
        )
        # return Builder.load_file('my_load2.kv')
        return self.root

    def callback(self, button):
        self.menu.caller = button
        self.menu.open()

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        self.menu.dismiss()
        Snackbar(text=text_item).open()

    def on_start(self):
        # Load the required .kv files for each tab
        Builder.load_file('screen1.kv')
        Builder.load_file('screen2.kv')
        Builder.load_file('screen3.kv')

        # Load the content of each screen into corresponding tabs dynamically
        for i, ScreenContent in enumerate([Screen1Content, Screen2Content, Screen3Content], start=1):
            tab_content = ScreenContent()
            tab = TabContent(title=f"Tab {i}")
            tab.content = tab_content
            self.root.ids.tabs_n.add_widget(tab)



    def on_tab_switch(
            self, instance_tabs, instance_tab, instance_tab_label, tab_text
    ):

        print(f"Welcome to {instance_tab.title}' tab'")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## load2.kv

```
       <TabContent>:
            MDLabel:
                text: root.title
                halign: 'center'
                font_style: 'H2'
        
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
        
            MDTopAppBar:
                id: top_bar
                pos_hint: {'top': 1}
                title: 'Regular Entry '
                # left_action_items: [['menu', lambda x: print(x)]]
                left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
                right_action_items: [["dots-vertical", lambda x: app.callback(x)]]
                # right_action_items: [['magnify', lambda x: print(x)], ['dots-vertical', lambda x: print(x)]]
        
            MDTabs:
                id: tabs_n
                tab_hint_x: True
```

## and in screen2.kv .

```
 <Screen2Content>:
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: dp(16)
                MDLabel:
                    text: "This is Screen 2"
                    halign: 'center'
```

So whats wrong in the code? There are no errors.